# HTML link not working correctly

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm trying to add links to my webpage. When I click on "Google" on my page, I get "Safari can't find the file". Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
</style>
<title>
Hola!
</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>
Hola!
</h2>
</br>
<h2>
<a href=“http://www.google.com/”>Google</a>
</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does it say when you try another browser? Say Google Chrome.

Comment: I get a similar thing in other browsers, but I'm also getting this: "Firefox can't find the file at .../Desktop/myfile/â€œhttp://www.google.com/â€. Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors. Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the double quotes in: `<a href=“http://www.google.com/”>Google</a>` are in asciformat.

Comment: Got it. For Mac Yosemite users, Textedit Preferences > uncheck 'Smart quotes'. Then System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > uncheck 'Use smart quotes and dashes' It seems the default settings have some characters in non ascii format. At first, it didn't change the characters, so I restarted my computer and then it worked.